# I want to make a viewport for a canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, viewport

So I have a game(that is more of a map) that loads a bunch of tiles and places them together. The tiles load just fine, but I'd like to move the viewport. I've looked into this subject, and I have a function that checks the keyboard. If 'd' is being pressed, I'd like to move the canvas so the viewport sees something different.

So far, the function for moving the canvas right looks like this:

```
function moveRight() {
ctx.translate(3000, 0);
imageSearch();
};
```

Where the imageSearch function updates the canvas. The updating, and loading etc. works fine, I just can't figure out how to move the canvas. Help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's a JSFiddle that 1j01 fixed for me: jsfiddle.net/jujhp0yv/1

The canvas still doesn't move though, so I'm still awaiting your responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the view port in a variable.

```
var view = {x: 0, y: 0};
```

Then, at the beginning of your draw loop / render function, save the canvas state and translate to the view port.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(view.x, view.y);
```

If you want `view.x` and `view.y` to represent the center of the view, instead translate like this:

```
ctx.translate(view.x - canvas.width/2, view.y - canvas.height/2);
```

At the end of your draw loop / render function, restore the state so translations won't stack up.

```
ctx.restore();
```

Now you should be able to modify `view.x` and `view.y` to move the view. (e.g. `view.x += 5`)

Comment: I added your suggestions, and it moved the canvas to the top right corner. I removed your suggestions, and it didn't change. Do you know what might have just happened?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I erased something in the CSS file by accident. I'll try your changes again, and if it doesn't work I'll give you a jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah, see you're loading the tiles as new images on every redraw, and that doesn't happen syncronously, so while the images are just starting loading, `ctx.restore()` is called and so it's still reset when drawing the images. Now, you could solve the immediate problem by moving the saving/translating/restoring to where the image is draw (`onload`), but you don't want to be loading images on every redraw anyways. What you want is to keep the images in a data structure like a 2d array.

Comment: I can't actually test this, because nothing will load, but http://jsfiddle.net/jujhp0yv/1/

Comment: All of the tiles load just fine, your method is pretty clever(thank you a lot), but I still can't quite get the canvas to move.

Comment: It works now! Thank you! I switched the way it translates to your other suggestion: ctx.translate(view.x - canvas.width/2, view.y - canvas.height/2);